# Keras ValueError: Shapes (?, ?, ?) and (6, 1) must have the same rank & logits and labels must have the same shape ((6, 1) vs (?, ?, ?)) when compile

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, nlp, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to build a NLP CNN model for multiclass-classification(6 classes). The first part of structure is:

Input --> Embedding --> Conv --> GlobalMaxPool --> Dropout --> Dense

And after the dense layer, each input sentence is converted to a 100 dimension embeddings.

After this, I'm passing in a constant matrix(6,100) which is a word embedding matrix of six different labels (each row represents a 100-dimensional word embedding) and I calculate the cosine similarity between the sentence embedding and each of the label word embedding as scoring function, and it gives me a result of (6,100).

Next, I pass the result of that to a dense layer to get output, using 1 neuron and sigmoid as activation which gives a result of (6, 1) but it's giving me that error in title when I compile it.

Below is all the code and I appreciate all the help!

MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH = 250

```
jdes_sequence_input = Input(shape=(MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,), dtype='float32')
word_embedding_layer = embedding_layer(jdes_sequence_input)
jdes = word_embedding_layer
jdes = Conv1D(filters=1000, kernel_size=5, strides=1, activation='tanh')(jdes)
jdes = GlobalMaxPooling1D()(jdes)
jdes = Dense(1000, activation='tanh')(jdes)
jdes = Dropout(0.3)(jdes)
jdes = Dense(100, activation='relu')(jdes)

def cosine_distance(input): # label_embedding is the constant matrix
    jd = K.l2_normalize(input, axis=-1)
    jt_six = K.l2_normalize(label_embedding, axis=-1)
    return jd * jt_six # return a 6*100 result

distance = Lambda(cosine_distance, output_shape=(6,100))(jdes)
result = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(distance)

model = Model(inputs=jdes_sequence_input, outputs = result)
sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.05)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(pad_data, labels, validation_split=0.2, batch_size=64, nb_epoch=1)
```

pad_data has shape: (18722, 250)
labels has shape: (18722, 6)

Answer (score 0):

It took a lot of time to understand the question and the error. The conclusion I reached is:

> Shapes (?, ?, ?) and (6, 1) must have the same rank

This tells that something is wrong with the output (with shape (6, 1)). You used a custom layer at the end of this model i.e. after the Dense layer. The error lies in that custom layer.

> distance = Lambda(cosine_distance, output_shape=(6,100))(jdes)

You defined the output shape to be (6, 100). My thinking here is, you forgot that the layers you write in Keras must be able to process the whole batch at once. Hence, the output should be of the shape (batch_size, 6, 100).

Now, the output_shape will be (?, 6, 100) which has rank '3' which is the same as rank of shape (?, ?, ?).

Give this a try..

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The error came from model.compile and it hasn't gotten to fit and know how much batch_size is. But what I did was: `distance = Lambda(cosine_distance, output_shape=(None, 6,100))(jdes)`.  And what I get when compile is `ValueError: Shapes (?, ?, ?, ?) and (6, 1) must have the same rank`. Am I doing it right? Thanks

Comment: Nope.. something is wrong. Can you provide the full error trace and the minimal code snippet? So that I can know which line is giving this error and which lines are indirectly affecting this error..

Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and it was with my custom distance lambda and the function I passed into it.

To fix it I have to do this

```
def get_abs_diff( vects ):
    x, y = vects
    return K.abs( x - y )  

def eucl_dist_output_shape(shapes):
    shape1, shape2 = shapes
    return (shape1[0], 1)
    #Original
    #return(1,) This messed up the ranking
```

This is not necessary the fix for your issue, but it is a place to start from. @Kadam Parikh was correct in that the issue is in the custom distance formula.